# How can I access a file with a .jpg&h=906 ending?

Tags: file-format

I've recently come across an image with the filetype, ".jpg&h=906" and for some reason I cannot view the image on my desktop computer once downloaded. Does anyone know anything about this filetype? Is it a corrupted file?

link: https://wearesodroee.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/alicia-vikander-michelle-williams-by-patrick-demarchelier-for-louis-vuitton-cruise-2016.jpg&h=906

Comment: Please keep each post to just one question - I'll edit out the second question, but feel free to repost it as a separate question (assuming that you've checked it hasn't already been answered on this site).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an incorrect premise due to misunderstanding the way web URLs work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a completely standard JPEG file with nothing special about it and no special protection. Your computer has simply become confused in downloading it due to the parameters in the URL. This is a bug or misconfiguration on your system, not a feature.

After it's been saved incorrectly, you can access it by simply renaming the file so it ends in just `.jpg`.

Comment: ... and you can safely remove the part after the ".jpg"

Comment: The original URL loads fine on my up to date Firefox 42.0 browser on Linux.  It's possible the OP's browser needs updating.